# Core Animation: resizing layer from just one side on iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I want to animate the resize of a `CALayer`. It needs to expand from the left (the right side needs to stay put). Setting the `anchorPoint` will make resizes work this way, but once I start animating, it doesn't behave the way I want it to.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks, and sorry for the noob-question.

Comment: You can animate the width of the bounds rect and set the position to move at half the rate, that way it should appear to not move or put a masking layer over the right side so you cannot see that half

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calculating a new position based on the desired resize, and setting the layer's `position` at the same time as you set its new bounds.